# Arbitrary accuracy of the fractional numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need a function of Matlab to do below operation (I don't know how to explain it in English)

suppose:

```
a = - 1.200000005
```

I need a function which does:

```
f(a) = -1.2; or f(a) = -1.2000
```

I mean, I want to set the arbitrary accuracy.

Comment: You can use the `sprintf` function. However, that returns just a string. Returning a number won't work like that. Example: `sprintf('%0.3f', 1.2000005)` --> `ans = 1.200`

Comment: How about [roundn](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/roundn.html) ?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior You are Awesome, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [output]=ArbAcc(a,digits)
    output = round(a*power(10,digits))/power(10,digits);
end
```

This creates a function `ArbAcc` which multiplies your data, rounds it and finally shifts it back to get your desired output.

Or, as @HamtaroWarrior said, use [`roundn`](http://mathworks.com/help/map/ref/roundn.html) (note that the mapping toolbox is required for `roundn`):

```
a = roundn(a,-digits);
```

If I had continued reading the documentation I would have seen that `roundn` is no longer recommended, use [`round`](http://mathworks.com/help/map/ref/round.html):

```
Y = round(X,N);% rounds to N digits
```

Comment: But it seems not to work in case of negative numbers ? Am I right ?  I think I need to write code to solve this problem

Comment: `roundn` digits are opposed to `ArbAcc` function @Adriann created. If you want to round to the 3rd number after the digit, `digits` need to be set as `-3`

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior Added a minus sign before `digits`. Now setting it to `3` does the same as in `ArbAcc`. Thanks!

Comment: @Cardinal if this answer worked for you, would you kindly consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it?